# Program type already present: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient$3

Tags: android, gradle, runtime-error, android-async-http

I am trying to build an app, but it failed compiling. I've tried to clean project, and when I tried to rebuild project, the same error appear.

I got this error from logcat:

```
Program type already present: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient$3
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient$3, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

and this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.joao.cafeclientapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
}
```

Comment: Please check and provide the outcome of dependency heierarchy for the mentioned  com.loopj.android.http via command gradlew app:dependencies

Comment: I tried to run this command `gradle app:dependencies` (because gradlew was not found) but it failed with this output `* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'CafeClientApp'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.`

Comment: I tried to simulate the dependency when the 'implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar') statement removed the project compiles without error. Else it is giving below error in Android Studio
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform file 'android-async-http-1.4.9.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform
   > Transform output file C:\codelab\MyApplication\app\libs\android-async-http-1.4.9.jar does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
```

Just remove the second line and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Implementation files ('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
```

To:

```
Compile files ('libs/android-async-http:1.4.9')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I went to the location of those files which were making problem during build process. I opened the infected files in file explore and deleted one of the duplicat files then I build the project again and it worked for me.

these files were located in below location:

> ..app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out